# Map item test as an expression

Tags: go

A Tour of Go explains how to test that a key is present in the map:

```
m := make(map[string]int)
m["Answer"] = 42
v, ok := m["Answer"]
if ok { Do Something if set }
if !ok { Do Something if not set }
```

Is there a way to test it without the assignment, expression way, something similar to this:

```
if m["Answer"] IS NOT NULL  { Do Something if set }
if m["Answer"] IS NULL  { Do Something if not set }
```

Or

```
fmt.Println(m["Answer"] == nil)
```

Comment: @Flimzy I need something you can put between `if` and opening `{`

Comment: **I have voted to reopen.** This is _clearly_ different question. You can see in the question that he is aware of the `value, exists := m["key"]` expression, and this question is **not** asking about it. He is asking about how to examine the presence of a key _without assignment_. Those can’t see it must be illiterate or blind.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying not to assign to the `v` and `ok` variables?

This is not possible. However, there is a short hand available:

```
if v, ok := m["Answer"]; ok {
    // Do something with `v` if set
} else {
    // Do something if not set, v will be the nil value
}
```

If you don't care about the value, but only that it's set, replace `v` with `_`.

```
if _, ok := m["Answer"]; ok {
    // Do something if set
} else {
    // Do something if not set
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_` as a placeholder if you don't care to store the value.

eg.

```
_, ok := m["Answer"]
if !ok {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Or, you can condense this a bit:

```
if _, ok := m["Answer"]; ok {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```